# Fill object with two array created by for loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, push, javascript-objects

Good morning,

I am learning Javascript and I am having some trouble creating objects and arrays with loops. I am sure this is has an easy solution but I was not able to find a solved problem or figure it by reading some examples.

Plotly code for plotting two variables is the following:

```
var trace1 = {
  x: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
  type: 'scatter'
};
var data = [trace1];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```

But when I try to create x and y through for loops and then fill the object trace1 with those arrays it seems to not work. The graphic appears but there is no data inside.

```
var x = [];
        for ( i = 0 ; i < 5; i++)
            x.push(x[i]=i);
        var y = [];
        for ( i = 0 ; i < 5; i++)
            y.push(y[i]=i);
        var type = 'scatter'
        trace1 ={x, y, type}

var data = [trace1];

    Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You should change `x.push(x[i]=i)` to `x.push(i)`.  The former, which you have used, is performing two operations: first it's setting `x[i] = i`, and then it's pushing the result of evaluating that (which is `i`) on to the end of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason, you have one entry extra in your arrays is that after first iteration `array x` looks like `x[0] = and x[1] = 0`. After second iteration it looks like
`x[0] = 0, x[1] = 1 and x[2] = 1`. Similarly for `y array`. This is due to side effect of assigning value to the array as well as pushing the result of assignment. This way it adds one extra entry in each iteration.

You need to do this:

```js
var x = [];
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  x.push(i);
var y = [];
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  y.push(i);
var type = 'scatter'
trace1 = {
  x,
  y,
  type
}

var data = [trace1];

console.log(x);
console.log(y);
//Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```js
var x = [];
for ( i = 0 ; i < 5; i++) { x.push(i); }

var y = [];
for ( i = 0 ; i < 5; i++) { y.push(i); }    

var type = 'scatter';
var trace1 = { x: x, y: y, type: type };

var data = [trace1];

    Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your object the same as you would in your first example of code.

```
var xArr = [];
for ( i = 0 ; i < 5; i++) {
  xArr.push(i);
}

var yArr = [];
for ( i = 0 ; i < 5; i++) {
  yArr.push(i);
}
var typeString = 'scatter'

trace1 = {
  x: xArr,
  y: yArr,
  type: typeString
}

var data = [trace1];
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```